# C++Can't find error, double free or corruption (fasttop)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, runtime-error

I am getting the following output from my program:

```
$ ./list
Enter list 1:   [1,2,3,4]
[
Enter list 2:   [2,5,8,0]
[
[1,2,3,4]
[1,2,3,4]
*** Error in `./list': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000f85100 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x80a46)[0x7fa0368d6a46]
./list[0x400d5f]
./list[0x400c62]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7fa036877ea5]
./list[0x400ae9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 410613                             /home/ubuntu/list
```

...

```
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
the endAborted (core dumped)
```

This is what I have in main:

```
int main(){
  pennlist::List l1,l2;

  cout<<"Enter list 1:\t";
  cin>>l1;
  cout<<"Enter list 2:\t";
  cin>>l2;
  cout<<l1<<endl<<l2<<endl;
  cout<<"the end";
}
```

And this this is the overloaded >> operator.

```
istream& operator >>(istream& ins, List& write_me){
    char discard;
    write_me.head = new node;
    write_me.current = write_me.head;
    node* temp = write_me.head;
    ins>>discard;//get [
    cout<<discard<<endl;

    while(discard != ']'){
      ins>>temp->data;
      write_me.count += 1;
      temp->to_tail = new node;
      temp->to_head = temp;
      temp = temp->to_tail;
      ins>>discard; //get , or ]
    }
    write_me.tail = temp;
    temp = NULL;
    return ins;
  }
```

I have overloaded the =, ~ and copy ctr as well and get the same error before and after adding these functions.

I can't figure out how to resolve this error, please help.

EDIT

```
Here is the code for the destructor:
~List{
    delete head;
    delete current;
    delete tail;
}
```

Comment: The only time I call delete is in pennlist::List::~List

{
  delete head;
  delete current;
  delete tail;
}

hmm.  Would delete head; and delete current; conflict if they are pointing to the same location?

Comment: The answer is yes. Thank you!

Comment: You should add the code that was causing the problem to your OP, and then answer your own question so others can learn from the solution. Also, might I recommend Valgrind (http://valgrind.org/) as a good tool for tracking down memory issues like this (and other, more complicated problems like memory leaks).

Comment: @MattPennington: Yes, `head` and `current` both point at the same location and you call `delete` twice.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. As I am sure you can tell, I am quite new at this.

Comment: compile with `g++ -ggdb -O0 -Wall` and run gdb - where does it break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the destructor, and the program now works correctly. Thanks everyone.

```
~List{
    if (head != current && tail != current)
        delete current;
    if (tail != head)
        delete tail;
    delete head;
}
```